# Indexing multilanguage site on search engines

Tags: php, seo, search-engine, multilingual, google-search

I have a multilanguage website which is structured in the following way:

index

- home
- pageA
- pageB
- pageC
- etc

Each page has it's own language file which is loaded dynamically with an select option.
When an option is select, also the meta tags (keywords, description, etc.) are loaded dynamically from external files in the index.php file.

What's the best practice to make it clear to the search engines that there are other languages than the default language?
Otherwise, does the search engines see the other language files? If yes, how would they see the other files?

Maybe it's not the best way from the seo point, but maintenance would be very easy, because the contents are separated from the pages.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has published a large amount of advice that helps them find and associate the appropriate language versions of sites and pages. You would effectively need to ensure every language version of the page is accessible directly by it's own URL, then use HTML mark-up in your HEAD, as per [the example from Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en):

> Update the HTML of each URL in the set by adding a set of rel="alternate" hreflang="x" link elements. For the default page that doesn’t target any specific language or locale, add rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default":
>
> `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com/" />`
>   `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="http://en-gb.example.com/page.html" />`
>   `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="http://en-us.example.com/page.html" />`
>   `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.example.com/page.html" />`
>   `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://de.example.com/seite.html" />`

Comment: Also my header is dynamically; it changes when the content AND when the language ist changing. There's no en.example.com, nor de.example.com. It's quite similare to a MVC, but not the same.

Comment: No, Google won't index/return permutations of content that dynamically changes. It will only return the state of the page it finds under it's crawl conditions. For your situation, ignore the sub-domains, but have examples in your own format that can provide unique URLs for each language variant of each page.

Answer (score 1):

Modern search engines are very smart and can crawl dynamic elements of websites. They automate the processes like button click, selection of an option from select menu etc. So, they will crawl all your language files by default you don't have to do anything.

Comment: So it won't be a problem to be indexed? Can you confirm? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No I cannot confirm because neither google nor bing or any other search engine reveals their algorithms. But if you observe their search results then you can find that they crawl dynamic contents. Here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en google says the same thing.

Comment: They may be able to *find* content this method, but it doesn't help with indexing and ranking for users, or helping them understand the relationship between the different versions of the pages.

Comment: Indexing & ranking has nothing to do with the language of the page.

Comment: In terms of the OP's question it does, if the aim is to have relevant language content found by search engines and returned in search results then that is precisely about *indexing* and *ranking*.

Comment: utf-8 is supported by all search engines, so indexing has nothing to do with language. Ranking has also nothing to do with language. When u search in english the english page is shown in search results, when u search in Hindi then Hindi page is returned. Ranking is done on websites, not pages of websites.

Comment: Rather than discuss, has anyone made some pratical experience with a dynamic website like mine? Thanks ;-)

Comment: "Ranking is done on websites, not pages of websites" - OK, if this is your working assumption then there's no point in me arguing, but I suggest you read the link in my answer (which was written for a reason), and then argue this statement with John Conde - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/14585/4461